# Cassandra High availability with different ESX hosts

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 5 machines cassandra cluster and 3 nodes belong to ESX1 host and other 2 machine belong to ESX2 host.
I have keyspace called profilemanager with replication factor 3. As per my understanding cassandra distribtes the data across multiple nodes based on replication factor.

Question: If keyspace profilemanager having replication factor 3 then there might be a chance that all 3 copies data can be held in ESX1 host.
If ESX1 goes down then all the corresponding 3 machines goes down then there will be no High availability. Is there a way to specify the machine to hold the replication for specific machine.

For Example: A,B,C,D,E machine are there. Two copies must be saved in A,B and third copy must be saved in D/E.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to solve this using Cassandra's feature for specifying logical data centers and racks.  If you use the `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` you should be able to specify the following in each ESX1 node's `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file:

```
dc=YourDatacenterName
rack=ESX1
```

And on each ESX2 node:

```
dc=YourDatacenterName
rack=ESX2
```

At write time, Cassandra then ensure that either secondary or tertiary replicas are streamed to nodes in another rack.  In this way, all replicas for a partition will not be on the same ESX host.